# Unable to replace a data source using lyr.replaceDataSource using variables

Tags: arcpy

What I'm trying to do is collect two .csv links and two layer identifications from the user, geocode the addresses in the .csv, and then change the data source on the identified layer in an open map to the geocoded results.  The geocoding works fine, but replacing the data source doesn't work.  It results in no error messages either, so I am having great difficulty tracking down the problem.

Here is a snippet of code:

```
mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc, "")[0]
lyrlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc, "*", df)
for lyr in lyrlist:
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        if lyr.dataSource == cup_lyr_file:
            lyr.replaceDataSource(where_to_save, "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE", cup_bname, "")
        elif lyr.dataSource == reg_lyr_file:
            lyr.replaceDataSource(where_to_save, "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE", reg_bname, "")
```

`where_to_save` is the workspace collected from the user as to where the geocoded files should be saved.  `cup_bname` and `reg_bname` are the baseNames of the geocoded shapefiles.

I am just now learning Python.  With no feedback at all from the program, I'm lost as to what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion: where you have IF...ELIF statements, add an ELSE statement to your code to let you know if none of your IF conditions are met. For example:

```
mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc, "")[0]
lyrlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc, "*", df)
for lyr in lyrlist:
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        if lyr.dataSource == cup_lyr_file:
            lyr.replaceDataSource(where_to_save, "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE", cup_bname, "")
        elif lyr.dataSource == reg_lyr_file:
            lyr.replaceDataSource(where_to_save, "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE", reg_bname, "")
        else print("dataSource is not cup_ or reg_ lyr_file.")
    else print("Layer does not support DATASOURCE.")
```

You would probably want to include the name of the layer or datasource in the `PRINT` function.

Comment: Where does the script print the message?  I tried putting in print commands in various places in the script (including one at the very beginning that should print 100% of the time) and never saw the message.

Comment: It should print them to the console window of whatever software you're using to run the script. I usually run mine in Pyscripter, any print commands show up in the "Python Interpreter" tab. You may need to turn on (or make active) the appropriate window/tab in your Python IDE.

Comment: Use `arcpy.AddMessage()` instead of `print()` to get the messages to appear in the Results tab in ArcMap.  So `print("dataSource is not cup_ or reg_ lyr_file.")` would become `arcpy.AddMessage("dataSource is not cup_ or reg_ lyr_file.")`

Comment: Thank you very much!  This was so useful!  I was able to query my variables and figure out that `cup_lyr_file` and `reg_lyr_file` did not have the values I expected them to have.  So that's why the script wasn't working.  I had no idea because it was running silently.

Comment: I also did add in an `else` statement for each `if`.  Thank you so much for your kindness and assistance.